# Is the finite partitioning principle equivalent to a form of choice??

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

By the finite partitioning principle I mean the following:

Every infinite set is the union of pairwise disjoint finite sets all larger than 1 in cardinality. In other words every infinite set can be partitioned into a family of non-singleton finite compartments.

Formally:

$$\forall \operatorname {infinite} X , \exists Y: \forall a,b \in Y (a \cap b =\emptyset \land 1 < |a| < \aleph_0) \land X=\bigcup Y$$

> Is this principle equivalent to $\sf AC$ or some known weaker form of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is vastly weaker than the axiom of choice, since it follows from $X+X=X$ for any infinite set $X$.

To wit, take a bijection between $X$ and $X\times\{0,1\}$, and then simply look at the partition into pairs that is induced by the bijection.

Comment: However, I don't think it's quite obvious that $X+X=X$ is strictly weaker than choice (since choice is after all equivalent to $X^2=X$). Do you have a citation for that offhand? I don't actually know one ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber That $X+X=X$ is strictly weaker than AC is a very nontrivial theorem of Sageev. (Halpern & Howard previously got the result in a permutation model with atoms; then Sageev got the result for ZF.)

Comment: @Zuhair No, "every infinite set is Dedekind-infinite" is **much weaker than** AC.

Comment: Asaf, is this principle weaker than $X+X=X$ or is it equal to it?

Comment: @Noah: I never claimed for that to be obvious. But it came up in past questions of Zuhair.

Comment: @Zuhair: I don't know. It's not obvious that it is equivalent, but it's not obvious that it's not. If I were a gambling man, I'd say that it's equivalent. But I don't know how to show it, not off hand, not without a bunch of finite combinatorics, which I'm not very good with.